# Spring 3 - What's the standard way of sending @RequestParam values back to the view?

Tags: java, spring, data-binding, spring-mvc, spring-3

I have a simple controller that handles a submit with a couple of parameters, not so much that I would consider creating a command object to store them.

In my controller I have annotated the parameters with `@RequestParam` but I have to send these values to the view and I don't know what's the best way of doing it.

If I had a command object I could use the `modelAttribute` on the `html:form` tag to bind the parameters but I don't want to create a command object for just a bunch of fields.

What is the preferred way of sending the values to the view (request attributes, model attributes ... )?

Comment: You can access the params of the request by using jstl in this way: for example for a param called "foo" you can get it by doing ${param.foo}. I don't know if that's enough for your needs but in this way you wouldn't need to add it to the model with the put method.

Comment: @Javi: You are correct, you can use ${param.foo} in the JSP to get back the value that was submitted, but that gives you no control over the value. If you must do some validations, fall-back to some default value etc, you can't do that in the view, and even if you could that's not the place to  do it. This is why I prefer to place  request parameters in the controller. Thanks for your comment though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd say model attributes. Something like

```
@RequestMapping("/path")
public void test(@RequestParam("q") String q, ModelMap model) {
    model.put("q", q);
}
```

On front end you could print it using your favourite approach. A sample with [JSTL](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnakh.html)

```
<html> 
   ...
   <c:out value="${q}" />
 </html>
```